# [apache][.htaccess] optional trailing slash

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want the .htaccess file to be able to process an optional trailing slash, so that both

```
localhost/Stuff/Test
localhost/Stuff/Test/
```

will work. I've searched for an answer, but all I found was that I needed '/?', and I already put that. Help? Here's my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ $1.php [NC] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule .* custom_404.html [L] 

</IfModule>
```

Currently it only works without the slash.

Answer (score 0):

Try thi code for php extension hiding:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^ custom_404.html [L]
```

Comment: No luck. It just occurred to me that my problem might be that the trailing slash is causing the redirected url to have 2 slashes side by side, so I'll look into that.

Comment: Do you have some other rules also not shown above OR other .htaccess in your system?

Comment: I have shown the entire .htaccess file, and there seem to be a couple of other .htaccess files within the xampp directory

Comment: Then you need to show content of each .htaccess and their filesystem locations.